# Require re-authentication for certain actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security

For certain actions like changing email settings or administrator activities, I want users to re-authenticate before the action is completed. Is there a good pattern for doing this in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Descpription

You can create your ActionMethod with `Username`, `Password` and the field you want to change (`Email`) for example. Than validate this data in the `[HttpPost]` of your data. If the authorization has success, change it and if not add the error to the `ModelState`.

Use a ViewModel for that.

#### Sample

```
public class ChangeEmailViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}


public ActionResult ChangeEmail()
{
    return this.View(new ChangeEmailViewModel());
}

public Action ChangeEmail(ChangeEmailViewModel model)
{
    // authorize
    bool isAuthorized = // your logic.
    if (isAuthorized)
    {
        // change email
    } else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Username is not valid");
    }

    return this.View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically intercept and re-authenticate someone who is already authenticated, you could probably also handle this with a special cookie. The actions that require re-auth could be decorated with a custom filter that overrides OnAuthorization to check for the cookie, then redirect to take username & password if it is not found. Pattern, no code:

```
User clicks link to uber-protected action.
Filter on action looks for cookie and does not find it, redirects to sign in.
User signs in, and you write a special cookie 
    (different from the forms auth cookie), 
    then redirect back to original action. 
Filter on action looks for cookie and finds it authorizing user.
```

The lifetime of the cookie would at least have to go all the way to the http post of the uber-protected action. You will have to decide when to delete it. For example, after user re-auths for one uber-protected action, do you want them to re-auth for second uber-protected action in the same browser session?